Oracle SQL Developer not opening on mac: "Module javafx.base not found"
I've just installed Oracle SQL Developer on my Mac, but I'm unable to open it. It just bounces on the task bar and won't open. When I try to run it through the Terminal, I get the following error:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found

I downloaded the SQLDeveloper version "Mac OSX with JDK 17 included," so I assumed JDK 17 would be bundled with it. I can see a JDK folder located at:
/Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/jdk
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

It's a problem with the DMG, we're working to get a new version out with this fixed, in the meantime use the previous version.
